# Overriding default and not plotting combinations of data on boxplot

Tags: python, pandas, plot, boxplot

I have a `dataframe` in the following format:

[image]

and I'm trying to `boxplot` it using the following code:

```
plot = toPlot.boxplot(column=['Score'], by=['Q1','Q2'])
plt.show()
```

which gives me the following plot:

[image]

As we can see in the above plot, the result has (T,F), (T,T), (F,T) etc combinations already made, which I don't want for my purposes.

I'd ideally like the following:

Plot these box plots separately like the graph below (which has been taken from [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html)) plots it. But I have multiple `Q1`, `Q2`....`Qn` etc. So I'd like to have these individual plots in rows and columns, more like a `scatterplotmatrix` or `facet_grid` in `R`.

[image]

Any pointers on how to achieve this?

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = plt.subplot(1,2,1)
df.boxplot(column='Score',by='Q1',ax=ax1)
ax2 = plt.subplot(1,2,2)
df.boxplot(column='Score',by='Q2',ax=ax2)
fig.suptitle('test title', fontsize=20)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you. The code worked fine but when I tried to extend this to the entire data frame having 27 columns, it failed and gave me an error. Details are explained on a separate SO question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37799865/grouper-for-columnname-not-1-dimensional