# ValueError: num must be 1 <= num <= 2, not 3

Tags: python, pandas, boxplot

I have the following `dataframe` that I generated using `pivot_table`:

[image]

and I'm using the following code to `boxplot` the multiple columns:

```
    fig = plt.figure()
for i in range(0,25):
    ax = plt.subplot(1,2,i+1)
    toPlot1.boxplot(column='Score',by=toPlot1.columns[i+1],ax=ax)
fig.suptitle('test title', fontsize=20)
plt.show()
```

I was expecting an output like the following:

[image]

But this code gives me the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-275-9c68ce91596f> in <module>()
      1 fig = plt.figure()
      2 for i in range(0,25):
----> 3     ax = plt.subplot(1,2,i+1)
      4     toPlot1.boxplot(column='Score',by=toPlot1.columns[i+1],ax=ax)
      5 fig.suptitle('test title', fontsize=20)

E:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.pyc in subplot(*args, **kwargs)
   1020 
   1021     fig = gcf()
-> 1022     a = fig.add_subplot(*args, **kwargs)
   1023     bbox = a.bbox
   1024     byebye = []

E:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.pyc in add_subplot(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1003                     self._axstack.remove(ax)
   1004 
-> 1005             a = subplot_class_factory(projection_class)(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1006 
   1007         self._axstack.add(key, a)

E:\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_subplots.pyc in __init__(self, fig, *args, **kwargs)
     62                     raise ValueError(
     63                         "num must be 1 <= num <= {maxn}, not {num}".format(
---> 64                             maxn=rows*cols, num=num))
     65                 self._subplotspec = GridSpec(rows, cols)[int(num) - 1]
     66                 # num - 1 for converting from MATLAB to python indexing

ValueError: num must be 1 <= num <= 2, not 3
```

I believe it's because there can only be 2 boxplots on one graph?

Any idea on how to fix this? Any pointers would be highly appreciated.

TIA.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Note that you only generate two subplots:

```
ax = plt.subplot(1,2,i+1)
```

The first argument is the number of plots in each row and the second the number of plots per column (see also [the matplotlib.pyplot.subplot documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplot)). So the total number of plots avaiable in your case is: `1*2 = 2`. If you want to create 25 you could for example use:

```
ax = plt.subplot(5,5,i+1)
```

5 plots per row and 5 per column add to a total number of `5*5 = 25`

Comment: Thanks so much. That was very silly from my end. Note to self: understand parameters properly before copy-pasting code available on the internet.